# why the contentmode of the uiimageview did not work?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, contentmode

yesterday when i code I am puzzled by a question about contentMode of UIImageView.I want to set UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to the UIImageView but the effect of that the image overflow the UIImageView,this is the result:![enter image description here][1]

The red frame is the UIImageView,in the pic we can see the content overflow the UIImageView.Why this happend?

This is the code:![enter image description here][2]

```html
    UIImageView* copySmall = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    copySmall.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    copySmall.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    [copySmall setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [copySmall setFrame:oriRect];
    [copySmall setImage:imgView.image];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set **clipToBounds = YES** for your imageView

Comment: Thanks!It's resolved my problem.But the clipTobounds property is used to clip subview to the father view,still confused.